# Can the Brier score and Concordance index be anti-correlated?

Tags: survival, scoring-rules, concordance

I am using a proportional hazards Cox model to predict the survival probability of some mechanical components. I am using a combined L1-L2 penalization, and I want to optimize the (integrated) Brier score, mostly because I would like to obtain the best probabilities, not so much the raking or ordering, which would imply optimizing for the Concordance index.
The hyper-parameter optimization is done using a 5-fold cross-validation scheme.

As I search for the best combination of parameters I observe that the Brier score and the C-index are anti-correlated: As the Brier score improves, the C-index goes down, and the other way around. In the worst case, I am getting a C-index of 0.5 for the best Brier score (about 0.06), and a Brier score of 0.25 for the best C-index (about 0.95).

What does this mean? I would expect them to be positively correlated. Is this an overfitting symptom?